# Makefile autocompletion for paths (e.g. for defconfig)

Tags: makefile, autocomplete

I have a project with a [menuconfig](https://github.com/kkrach/menuconfig) configuration for which this I use several *_defconfig files as default configurations. These defconfig files are grouped for each project:

```
/
  - projects
    - projectA
      - configs
         - 32bit_defconfig
         - 64bit_defconfig
         - foo_defconfig
    - projectB
      - configs
         - 32bit_defconfig
         - 64bit_defconfig
         - bar_defconfig
```

Now I would like to have a makefile, where I get the autocompletion for these defconfigs:

```
$ make projects/pr<TAB>
projects/projectA
projects/projectB
```

I thought about writing a Makefile like this:

```
projects/%/configs/%_defconfig: FORCE
    echo $@
```

Currently the only thing which is working is this rule, where I have no autocompletion for the path:

```
# e.g. 'make projects/88000-000/configs/32bit_defconfig'
%_defconfig: FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f tools/make/menuconfig.mk $@
```

PS: Autocompletion works for regular make targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards for this reason:

```
DEFCONFIGS=$(wildcard projects/*/configs/*_defconfig)

test: FORCE
    echo $(DEFCONFIG)

$(DEFCONFIGS): FORCE
    $(MAKE) -f tools/make/menuconfig.mk $@
```

First use the test-target to check whether your wildcard is working, then you can use autocompletion:

```
$ make <TAB>
all                      default                  install_toolchain
buildroot-menuconfig     FORCE                    menuconfig
clean                    install                  projects/
$ make projects/<TAB>
92107-110/  BananaPro/
$
```